# .htaccess that adds www. in front the main domain only, leaving subdomains untouched

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have a domain called 'example.com'. I need a htaccess file that adds 'www.' in front of the main domain 'example.com' when the users types the main domain name without 'www.'.
I also want to create lots of subdomains, let's say 'sub1.example.com', 'sub2.example.com' and 'sub3.example.com'. I want all subdomains that I create to be left unchanged, whenever the user enters them with 'www.' or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumbled upon the answer...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```